# Jquery/Javascript function chain, need some tips (sync/async)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise

Code is working with promises on needed parts, but i have dude on single functions chain, working and returning objects. Example is like...

```
tableInit: function() {
        this.$wrap = $('#'+ this.options.baseId +'Wrap');
        this.$table = this.tableBuild();
        this.$wrap.append(this.$table);

        this.loadResults();
    },

tableBuild: function () {
        var $table = $('<table>');
        $table.append(this.tableHeadBuild());
        return $table;
    },

tableHeadBuild: function () {
        var self = this;
        var $thead = $('<thead>').addClass('thead-light');
        var $row = $('<tr>');
        $row.append('<th>');

        $.each(self.options.columns.active, function(key, params){
            var $cell = $('<th>');
            $cell.attr('id',params.id).text(params.lang);
            $row.append($cell);
        });

        $thead.append($row);

        return $thead;
    },
```

Should be tableBuild and tableHeadBuild designed as promises to secure great linear work? When really we need promises? (on async ajax calls for sure)

```
tableInit: function() {
    ...
    this.tableBuild().then(function(table){
        self.$wrap.append(this.$table);
        self.loadResults();
    });
    ... 
},

//or like...
tableInit: function() {
    ...
    this.$table = this.tableBuild()
    this.$table.promise().done(function(){
        self.$wrap.append(this.$table);
        self.loadResults();
    });
    ... 
},
```

I think i have some bad concepts, please, some tips. Thanks!

Comment: What you want to do is return a Promise when loading results, then resolve that Promise after you have a response. All the rest is immediate and doesn't really make sense as async code.

Comment: Thanks @ehmprah . So, should i only use on ajax calls, timeouts or when really i have to wait a response (user/server interact)? What happend with long time execution functions?